# Rounding decimals with new Python format function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How do I round a decimal to a particular number of decimal places using the Python 3.0 `format` function?

Comment: Just posted this question because I wasted 15 minutes trying to understand the documentation http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#formatspec. They really should include this in an example

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Here's a typical, useful example...:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> p = math.pi
>>> '{0:.{1}f}'.format(p, n)
'3.1416'
```

the nested `{1}` takes the second argument, the current value of n, and applies it as specified (here, to the "precision" part of the format -- number of digits after the decimal point), and the outer resulting `{0:.4f}` then applies.  Of course, you can hardcode the `4` (or whatever number of digits) if you wish, but the key point is, you don't **have** to!

Even better...:

```
>>> '{number:.{digits}f}'.format(number=p, digits=n)
'3.1416'
```

...instead of the murky "argument numbers" such as 0 and 1 above, you can choose to use shiny-clear argument *names*, and pass the corresponding values as *keyword* (aka "*named*") arguments to `format` -- that can be **so** much more readable, as you see!!!

Comment: I think I read about the nesting trick before. That is quite neat, thanks for reminding me

Comment: @Casebash, you're welcome!  I do agree that the `format` approach is vastly superior to the old-fashioned, C-inspired `%`-operator based formatting -- their power's roughly equal, but `format` is _vastly_ more usable!-)

Comment: Like the use of named arguments instead of {0:.{1}f}, you're right IMO it's *way* more readable as number:.{digits}f. Another plus is that the named arguments can be more readily recycled and don't necessarily need to be in order.

Comment: wow, I didn't know it is possible to do nested format like this

Answer (score 29):

An updated answer based on [Alex Martelli]'s solution but using Python 3.6.2 and it's updated format syntax I would suggest:

```
>>> n=4
>>> p=math.pi
>>> f'{p:.{n}f}'
'3.1416'
```

But by choosing your variables wisely your code becomes self documenting

```
>>> precision = 4
>>> pi = math.pi
>>> f'{pi:.{precision}f}'
'3.1416'
```

Answer (score 24):

In Python 3.x a format string contains replacement fields indicated by braces thus::

```
".... {0: format_spec} ....".format(value)
```

The format spec has the general layout:

```
[[fill]align][sign][pad][width][,][.precision][type]
```

So, for example leaving out all else but width, precision and type code, a decimal or floating point number could be formatted as:

```
>>>print("The value of pi is {0:10.7f} to 7 decimal places.".format(math.pi))
```

This would print as:

```
The value of pi is  3.1415927 to 7 decimal places.
```

Answer (score 8):

To round x to n decimal places use:

```
"{0:.{1}f}".format(x,n)
```

where 0 and 1 stand for the first and second arguments of the str.format() method, respectively.

Comment: Nice! With named arguments: `"{x1:.4f} and {x2:.4f}".format(x1=1.23456789, x2=9.87654321)` yields `'1.2346 and 9.8765'`  (the curly braces immediately after the decimal didn't work for me, but could apparently be omitted)

Answer (score 4):

I just found out that it is possible to combine both the `{0}` and the `{digits}` notation. This is especially useful when you want to round all variables to a pre-specified number of decimals *with 1 declaration*:

```
sName = 'Nander'
fFirstFloat = 1.12345
fSecondFloat = 2.34567
fThirdFloat = 34.5678
dNumDecimals = 2

print( '{0} found the following floats: {1:.{digits}f}, {2:.{digits}f}, {3:.{digits}f}'.format(sName, fFirstFloat, fSecondFloat, fThirdFloat, digits=dNumDecimals))
# Nander found the following floats: 1.12, 2.35, 34.57
```

=============================================================

EDIT:

Since all answers (including mine) where using the 'old' `{0}.format()` method, I'm now adding the new f-strings method ([Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings), Python 3.6+ I think) too:

```
x = 1.2345
y = 23.45678

print(f'x = {x:.2f} and y = {y:.2f}')
#x = 1.23 and y = 23.46
```