# Getting a number of digits

Tags: python, rounding, decimal

I've been searching for a way in python to get only 4 digits on the right of the comma of a decimal number, but i couldn't find. Took a look on this post,---> [Rounding decimals with new Python format function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598579/rounding-decimals-with-new-python-format-function) 
,but the function written there...

```
    >>> n = 4
    >>> p = math.pi
    >>> '{0:.{1}f}'.format(p, n)
    '3.1416'
```

...seems not to work in my case.

I imported the modules "math" and "decimal", but maybe i'm missing some others to import, but i don't know which of them to import.

Thanks everyone, and sorry if this issue has already been posted.

Peixe

Comment: `seems not to work in my case.` what is not working ? what error you get ? please provide more detail.

Comment: That's probably because you're using Python 2, instead of Python 3.

Comment: This is the error I get when i pass the function to my data...:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

I'm trying just to sum some numbers in a list, an I need them to have the same number of decimals.
This is all... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"%.3f" % math.pi
```

I know its using the old syntax but I personally prefer it.

Comment: @Jakob Bower: i'd prefer it too, however there is subtle difference (or a bug?) from OP's method in rounding accuracy, e.g. `"%.4f" % 0.11115` will result in `0.1111`, however, `"%.3f" % 0.1115` -> `0.112`... weird

Comment: I think thats just floating point, Im not sure if .format does it differently but still floating point math is not right.

Comment: @Jakob Bower: well, i was to naive to expect that str.format will behave differently :) BTW, is `"%.xf" % round(float,x)` ok for such 'edge' cases?

Comment: Thank u all guys, this function "%.3f" % math.pi did my job...!
;)

Comment: @barti_ddu I don't really do 'that' much floating point math so im not sure.

Comment: @barti_ddu: You have the same issue with both kind of formatting, and with `round(0.11115, 4)`

Comment: @Rosh Oxymoron: well, it works on 2.6.6 (evaluates to 0.1111(9)) but on 3.1 - does not. At least this behaviour is officially declared (but looks weird, anyway). And thanks for commenting.

Comment: @barti: the only python-version independent method I can use to explain the 0.11115 and 0.1115 rounding “discrepancies” is: `import math; math.frexp(0.11115), math.frexp(0.1115)`. Both numbers can't be stored exactly. Check the mantissas: the former suggests that floating point 0.11115 is a little less than round 0.11115, and floating point 0.1115 is a little greater than round 0.1115.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine (rounding the 5 up to a 6)

If you want truncation instead of rounding you could go:

```
from math import pi as p
print p
print int(p*10**4)/10.0**4

p=str(p).split(".")
p[1]=p[1][:4]
print ".".join(p)
```

output:

3.14159265359

3.1415

3.1415

Comment: Hey, this solution did the job as well! It's good and simple!

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if you wanted rounding or not. Up vote if you like.

Comment: I would like to upvote, but i need 15 reputation, it says... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the remainder of a float you could convert to a string and split on `'.'`:

```
>>> str(math.pi).split('.')[1][:4]
<<< '1415'
```

or `decimal.Decimal`:

```
>>> Decimal(math.pi).as_tuple()[1][1:5]
<<< (1, 4, 1, 5)
```