# Decimal Precision in odoo 8

Tags: python, precision, odoo-8

Decimal precision `Product price` is already set like `digit=2`,
I am fetching the price field data
the value is `69.00`

The field is defined like:

```
'list_price': fields.float('Sale Price', help="Base price to compute the customer price. Sometimes called the catalog price."),
'lst_price' : fields.related('list_price', type="float", string='Public Price', digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
```

but it displays `69.0`
it ignores zero, I want to print as it is(`69.00`)
how can I do that?

Comment: I done it,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598579/rounding-decimals-with-new-python-format-function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `Product Price` in `Decimal Accuracy`?

If not then you can set it step-by-step like this...

1. First go to **settings -> Users -> Administrator(Your username)**

And Tick **Technical Features**

[image]

2. Then go to **Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy -> Product Price**

and edit `Digit = 2`

[image]

I hope it will help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

hello add this one attribute on the field of 'list_price': **digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price')**

```
'list_price': fields.float('Sale Price', help="Base price to compute the customer price. Sometimes called the catalog price.", digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price'))
```

related fields it's mean compute field so try above suggestions i hope so this one helpful for you